# How to retrieve a key based on the value in Map Interface Java?

Tags: java

I am currently working on Data Structures for writing a program on encryption and decryption of names. I have a doubt in Map interface. Actually to get the value associated with a key we have get() method in Map interface. But how to retrieve the key of a particular value without iterating through all the key value pairs in Map interface

Thank you

Comment: can anyone please recommend me a data structure through which i can solve my problem? actually i have tried using Entry interface but i am not getting it

Comment: what exactly  you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well like everyone said, you can't really do it in a decent way because there can be duplicate values. You could search for a hit using the equals() method and compare values. but then again, why are you even using a key/value map if you wanted to do such a thing.

in short, you could write your own version of the get method, taking in a instance of the value object you are trying to get. But there really is not a point in using a map if you are going to do that.

Why not use a list of some sorts of you desire to search on value ?

Comment: thank you and yes i can but i need boht the key and value. value for encryption process and key for decryption process. So can you recommend me any data structure through which the problem can be solved

Comment: `value for encryption process and key for decryption process.` - Why don't you just maintain a normal map ?

Comment: @Srividya Well, if you can't really find a data structure in existence you want to use, nothing is preventing you from creating an object containing all the data you want :). you could create your own container class, and store that in a collection (e.g. arraylist<yourobjecttype>) and access all the members you want. but you should keep in mind that you will need a unique way to identify objects. in a map normally that would be the key.

Answer (score 2):

> how to retrieve the key of a particular value without iterating through all the key value pairs in Map interface

**Key is Key, not the value**. You cannot do it. That's not how Map implemented.

Even If you make it with some magic (*iterating multiple times, checking for equls etc ..*), that's not guaranteed to give expected result..

And as per the definition of Map, Key is unique not the value. So there will be duplicated values and when you get by value, which associated key you will expect to get ?

If you are sure that there are no duplicates, you can do

```
 for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : testMap.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().equals("c")) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, it can't be done. The `Map` interface and its implementations do not support that.

Consider using a `BiMap` such as the one inculed in Google Guava Collections. It establishes a one-to-one (bidirectional) relationship between keys and values.
https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#BiMap

Using `BiMap` you can use `Key key = biMap.inverse().get(value)` to get a key for a given value.

Comment: Broken link, correct: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#bimap

Answer (score 2):

Given that values are unique, you could to it like this:

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("key1", "value1");
    map.put("key2", "value2");

    String key = map.entrySet().stream().
    collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey))
    .get("value1");

    System.out.println(key); //gives key1
```

Comment: Could also try `Collectors.groupingBy` which can give you a list of keys associated with each value.

Comment: How is this different than iteration?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that because the "values" can be duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

As said, that is not provided by Java-Map interface, since you should have a key and get the value then.

Usually you have something like this.

```
User user = ...;
HashMap<String, User> usernamesToUser = ...
```

Then you can get the key by something like:

```
String username = user.getUsername();
```

So without using the map actually.
However what you can do is, if the key is not directly to retrieve from the object you can use two Maps for both directions. So consider former example (just assume User the User object does not safe the Username)

```
Map<User, String> userMapReverse = ....;
Map<String, User> userMap = ....;
String username = userMapReverse.get(user);
```

However this option requires that you maintain two maps, which can be pretty ugly sometimes.